# How do you access a pointer to a pointer for an id object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, jailbreak

I am dabbling in jailbreak development/tweaks and I already know that this goes against Apple's SDK rights, etc. I am fairly new to objective-c and am unsure how to access a pointer to a pointer to a value. Here is the header function:

```
- (id)_newCKSMSMessage:(id *)arg1;
```

I have tried several attempts to get access to the value of arg1:

```
id msg = &arg1;
id *msg = &arg1;
```

How do I access the value being pointer to by arg1?

Comment: @sidyll: It's a little awkward, but there's not really any better way to accomplish the same thing, so we'll all have to suck it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have another problem that you don't know you have.

The argument to this method is most likely *not a valid object*. When you see a pointer to a pointer to an object, that is almost always a "return by reference" parameter. The caller passes in the address of some variable, and the method is supposed to set the variable to some object. For example:

```
- (void)tellMeHello:(id *)message {
    if (message) {
        *message = @"Hello!";
    }
}

// It's used like this:

id thisWillBeTheMessage; // it's nothing right now
[someObject tellMeHello:&thisWillBeTheMessage];
NSLog(@"%@", thisWillBeTheMessage); // prints "HELLO!"
```

I'm not familiar with the method in question here, but there's pretty much no other reason to pass a pointer to a pointer to an Objective-C object AFAIK.

EDIT: OK, I just thought of another reason: If  you're passing a C array of objects. But that's much less common. It's pretty much only done in a couple of NSArray initializers. It's more the exception than the rule.

Comment: This makes sense, especially with other methods in the same header with names like "addMessage" and "setMessage". Thank you for this, it probably saved me a few hours of trying the wrong thing!

Answer (score 1):

Before you dereference a pointer you have to make sure to check if it's NULL;

```
if(NULL != arg1) {
    id msg = *arg1;
    NSLog(@"msg = %@, [msg class] = %@", msg, NSStringFromClass([msg class]));
}
```

When you pass an object to _newCKSMSMessage:(id*)arg1 you do that like this;

```
id gak = [[Gak alloc] initWithInterestingStuff:interestingStuff];
[something _newCKSMSMessage:&gak];
```

It is improper for you to have methods that begin with '_'. You are likely to conflict with Apple's private methods if you do that.

Comment: this is one of Apple's private methods (from a dumped header), and I am trying to hook it, make sense of arg1, and then return the original function. I have tried id msg = *arg1 but when I try logging msg I get __NSCFType. I tried accessing &msg but that causes a crash. I appreciate the quick reply

Comment: You are trying to understand what Apple is doing there? Perhaps we should backup and discuss what you are trying to do. If you are logging with NSLog(@"%@", msg) and getting '__NSCFType' then its one of the toll-free-bridged objects.

Comment: I am trying to intercept the sender's number to an incoming sms message so that I can pop up a reply box as opposed to having to go to the MobileSMS.app and then switch back to my current application. This is more of a learning process for me to learn how things work. I don't necessarily need to understand everything Apple is doing, just how to turn arg1 into an understandable structure, dictionary, or array of information. I am unsure what you mean by toll-free-bridged objects (sorry, still new)

Comment: updated the sample code to reflect something you could do, the google knows toll-free-bridged objects

Comment: Unfortunately this causes a problem:                          Tweak.xm:45: warning: incompatible Objective-C types returning ‘objc_class*’, expected ‘NSString*’

Answer (score 1):

This is fundamental to C. Here's an example:

```
int val = 5;
int* valPtr = &val;        //valPtr points to val;
int** valPtrPtr = &valPtr; //valPtrPtr is a pointer to a pointer to val
int newVal = **valPtrPtr;  //newVal = 5
```

Let's say you have a pointer to a pointer called `vPtr`. Whenever you want to de-reference vPtr, you use `(**vPtr)` or `*vPtr[k]` for some k or `vPtr[j][k]` for some `j,k`. If accessing the value with array notation, be sure to have correct bounds or else you get undefined behavior.

Comment: While this should work, I think @Chuck pointed out that my problem was beyond the basics of pointers and had to do with the way Apple is calling this method. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `&` a `address of` operator?

So `id msg = &arg1` would mean pointer to `arg1` (third level!)

You should do `id msg = *arg1`